# Prove that a rational function is globally nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I need help showing that

$$f(x,y) := \frac{2 (4 x+5)k}{\left(2 x^2+5 x+y+4\right)^3}+\frac{-4 x-5}{\left(2 x^2+5 x+y+4\right)^2}+\frac{2}{(x+y+2)^2}\geq 0$$

with $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$, and $\frac{2 x^2+3 x+2}{2 x+1}>y$. Here $k\geq0$ is a free variable for us to choose, i.e., if we can say that for $k = 1$, the function is always non-negative, that will be great.

I've tried differentiating but $f_y$ is not always negative, so I can't substitute $y=\frac{2 x^2+3 x+2}{2 x+1}$ and show that that is always positive for some values of $k$.

I'm wondering if I could write it as an optimization problem:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(x,y)\\ \text{subject to} & x, y \geq 0\\ & \dfrac{2 x^2+3 x+2}{2 x+1} > y\end{array}$$

and show that the minimal value is greater than $0$. Are there any algorithms to solve this? It's probably not convex.

Comment: To clarify: you just need to prove that there is *some* value of $k > 0$ such that $f$ is positive on the specified domain?

Comment: Yup! That is correct.

Comment: How about reducing to a common denominator and then checking only whether the (polynomial) numerator is globally nonnegative? The pesky singularities one can worry about later. Deciding the global nonnegativity of a multivariate polynomial of relatively low arity and low degree is sometimes computationally cheap.

Comment: I do not know whether exists some $k$ for practical purposes. If you rewrite your function as $$ f(x,y) = \dfrac{2(4x+5)}{(2x^2+5x+y+4)^3}\left(k+g(x,y)\right),$$ a local minimum of $g(x,y)$ under non negative constraints ($x\geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$) is approximatelly $-8.2169\cdot 10^{11}$, which implies $k > 8.2169\cdot 10^{11}$. See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+-(2x%5E2%2B5x%2By%2B4)%2F2%2B(2x%5E2%2B5x%2By%2B4)%5E3%2F((4x%2B5)*(x%2By%2B2)%5E2),+x+%3E%3D0,+y%3E%3D0) for more details.